# splitting a string and count occurrences sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns:
feedbackID, gradeList.

feedbackID(int) - is the id of the table
gradeList(varchar(100)) - is a string of grades splits by ','.
a grade is between [0-1]
example: 1,0.5,1,0,0.2

I want to get the percentage of successes for each row.
the percentage of success for the example above is: 0.4

I came up with the query below, its working fine but it is kind of slow.
any suggestions how i can do it faster?

```
    SELECT Distinct FeedbackID          
    , S.a.value('count(/H/r[.=1])', 'INT') AS countingSuccesses
    , S.a.value('count(/H/r)', 'INT') AS countingAll            
    FROM (            
        SELECT *,CAST (N'<H><r>' + REPLACE(gradeList, ',', '</r><r>')  + '</r></H>' AS XML) AS [vals]
        FROM FEED_QuestionsGenerator as QEFB
     )  as d
     CROSS APPLY d.[vals].nodes('/H/r') S(a)
```

Comment: Can you change the data model to have each of the grades in separate row in an own table? The other option is to use string splitting function like DelimitedSplit8k, but no idea if that's faster or slower.

Comment: I agree with @JamesZ about your table structure. What you have violates 1NF and causes nothing but pain. If you properly normalize your data the dml is painless.

Comment: I can change the table structure but it will take a lot of time and a lot of work. i know that it violates the 1NF but we needed that value with the ','  for the server. I still wonder if it can be done faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compared my method to one using Split function and the execution plan shows that query 1 cost 100% relative to the batch
and query 2 cost 0% relative to the batch so i can safely assume that using split is much faster.

here is the code using Split:

```
SELECT gradeList,
    (
        (SELECT sum(cast(Data AS FLOAT)) FROM dbo.Split(gradeList,',') WHERE Data = '1')/
        (SELECT count(cast(Data AS FLOAT)) FROM dbo.Split(gradeList,',') )
    ) AS AnswersPrecentage FROM [Feed_QuestionsGenerator]
```